# Recover function based on integral area

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

I'm trying to recover a function based on the area under its curve. The domain of the function itself is in the $[0; 1]$ interval, and all I know is that the area between $0$ and any $x$ value between $0$ and $1$ equals to $1-x$ (eg. $\int_0^{0.1}f(t)dt = 0.9$, $\int_0^{0.3}f(t)dt = 0.7$ etc. $\int_0^1 f(t)dt = 0$. It seems to have a hyperbolic shape and negative function values for some points, can anyone please give me some hints on how I can recover the exact function for this?

-- UPDATE

I've already got an awesome suggestion from @draks with the Heaviside Step Function and I know that as the value of the integral decreases with x increasing, the function I'm looking for must have negative values. However, I wonder whether there exists a function with positive values.

Basically I'm trying to visualize the generalized 80-20 rule (in the form of the x - (100 - x) rule): the set of points in the first 20% (hence $\int_0^{0.2}$) have a collective utility of 0.8, the set consisting of the first 10% will have a collective utility of 0.9 and so on. The main reason I wonder whether such function with positive values exists is whether a specific utility value can be mapped to the specific point lying on the very boundary between the first 20% and the remaining 80% (ie. what is each member's utility in a group or a set based on their ordering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think
$$
\int_0^x \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \biggr(\delta(y-\epsilon)-1\biggr) dy =\\
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_0^x \biggr(\delta(y-\epsilon)-1\biggr) dy = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \big(H(y-\epsilon)-y\big)\Biggr|_0^x\\=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}  \biggr(H(x-\epsilon)-H(0-\epsilon)-x-0\biggr)=1-x,
$$
where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside Step Function, would do.
I additionally assume $x>\epsilon$.

So avoid the problems, concerning the half-mean convention, your "function" would look like 
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \biggr(\delta(y-\epsilon)-1\biggr)
$$
and would actually be a distribution.

Comment: So the function I'm looking for is $\delta(y)-1$?

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of the 5 minutes editing time limit. Can you help me elaborate how the LHS becomes the RHS? Why wont $\int_0^x\delta(y) - 1 dy$ just become H(x) - x - H(0) + 0 = 1 - x - 0.5 + 0 = 0.5 - x? Or you're just not using the half-mean convention for H(0)? But even then, how will H(x) - H(0) = 1 - 0 become 2H(x) - 1?

Comment: @AndrásHummer I updated my answer...

Comment: So this would make $f(x) = 0$ for every $y$ in $]0; 1]$. I see. Thank you, this is awesome. Actually, do you need any additional education to be able to solve problems like these besides calculus?

Comment: I meant $f(x) = -1$ as $\delta(y - \epsilon)$ would be 0 everywhere. Would that make $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_0^\epsilon f(t) dt = 1$?

Comment: @AndrásHummer I'm not a mathematician. Google "distributions" for more information. Concerning your last question: I'm not sure what happens in this case, sorry...